# Linq query giving Invalid column name "xyz" error

Tags: linq, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4

I am using this LINQ query

```
var db = new XYZ();
var product = (from cp in db.CatalogProducts
               where cp.ProductID == productId
               select cp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Running this query gives me an error

> Invalid column name 'Cracker Cruncher'.
>   Invalid column name 'crushing torque'.
>   Invalid column name 'Slicing velocity'.

Can any one help me in this matter?

Gautam

Comment: I am using sql2005, I am using LINQ to entities, table is huge.. I have not changed anything in DB. The error is coming only for 3 products that I added recently. for others(older ones) its still working..

Comment: Do these three columns exists in (1) your entity model (EDMX file or code-first classes), and (2) do they exist in the database table? I would think this error happens is something is out of sync - you've changed something, and not synchronized it with the other parts of your system.

Comment: The columns are present at both the places. I have made no recent changes to DB design. That is why I was wondering why I am getting this error.

Comment: Issue Resolved.. Just now I checked that Some1 has made drastic changes to DB without informing me..
Thanks for keeping up with me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved.. Just now I checked that Some1 has made drastic changes to DB without informing me.. Thanks for keeping up with me